# Typescript dynamically create types based on object

Tags: typescript

It's possible to dynamically generate type annotation by simply analyze an object properties, example an object like:

```js
cons myObj = {
        start() { /*...*/ },
}
```

I want to generate/return the follow type:

```
type Props = {
  start: () => void;
  isScreenStart: () => boolean;
  isStartAllowed: () => boolean;
}
```

Given a property like `advance`, it should generate the follow types

```
advance: () => void;
isScreenAdvance: () => boolean;
isAdvanceAllowed: () => boolean;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will be possible with the [latest TS version](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/) (4.1):

```
type Generate<T> = {
    [K in keyof T & string as T[K] extends Function ?
    `isScreen${capitalize K}` | `is${capitalize K}Allowed` :
    never]: () => boolean
} & T

type Generated = Generate<typeof myObj> 
// { isScreenStart: () => boolean; isStartAllowed: () => boolean; } & { start(): void; }
```

You can take a look  at [this sample code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=next#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWMC8MDeAoGQmaAQwCcoAKASlxgHoAqAOlcfpgF8AaPTvPFAQAHAKYwA4qLCiyJKKIA8AFQB8WXASIBtANIwAlmBgBrUQhAAzGMpgAyYlDJGA5jBIQbegLoxRADwUwABNPADEAVzBgKANwGAB%20LUIAAwMIAGVgMlFpABIcYBJhAygSABsDAC9xXU4UmAAfGDSIAqKSssqamDqAQXLykAB3UWCGgC5kmBkAN1lvCZgaLHUUEBBy0RIwPnsbASExSWlZeTGNKRk5BUUj0St4ZHR1PHoOHENM7NywDLKKEsVpg1hstjsANxff7kKADIajYJA2ggmDrTbbMBQzj7T6kCg0JazEAGYLYoA). Be aware, that the compiler keyword  `capitalize` is [subject to change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40580) for the final release.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: And `capitalize` did change.  You can correct the above code by replacing `capitalize K` with `Capitalize<K>`.