# Dynamic Typescript object properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to dynamically extend a type so that I can do the following:

```js
interface SurveyQuestion {
  propertyName: string,
  propertyType: Object,
}

const questions: SurveyQuestion[] = [
  { propertyName: "isNewUser", propertyType: typeof Boolean },
  { propertyName: "satisfactionScore", propertyType: typeof Number },
  { propertyName: "comments", propertyType: typeof String },
];

type SurveyWithQuestions = {
  date: Date;
  username: string;
}

let survey1: SurveyWithQuestions = { 
  date: new Date("1/1/2023"),
  username: "johndoe",
  isNewUser: true,
  satisfactionScore: 5,
  comments: "happy user"
};
```

...so that new questions added will not error and will allow code completion for them.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63995567/typescript-dynamically-create-types-based-on-object) gets close using generics and object keys.  But I couldn't modify it properly to iterate questions.

Comment: Why is this tagged "typescript-eslint"? Do you have some linter config that's relevant here?  If so, what is it?  If not, maybe untag?

Comment: `typeof Boolean` and `typeof Number` and `typeof String` are almost certainly not what you want; those are just the string `"function"`.  And `Object` is also almost certainly not what you want, since that matches any non-nullish value, including the string `"function"`, which is why that's not an error.  Could you please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that actually demonstrates what you're trying to do, at least the runtime code? Then we can help you give it typings.

Comment: *Perhaps* [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBJlbN) is what you want, but I had to make a lot of guesses and I'm not sure how you expect to use it (where and when are you going to "add" new questions?  How are you really going to encode what types the property types are? etc).  If that works for you I could write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that is exactly how I expect to use it; adding new SurveyQuestions to the array automatically adds those strongly-typed properties to the SurveyWithQuestions object.  That way I can use code completion and not have to keep property names in multiple places.  Thanks for your TS wizardry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to presume that the `propertyType` property will be a string that describes the type, like `"boolean"` or `"date"`.  If so, then for this to work you'll need to keep a type that maps from these strings to the TypeScript types they represent:

```
interface TypeMap {
    boolean: boolean;
    number: number;
    string: string;
    date: Date;
    // add any name-to-type mappings you need here
}
```

and then we can say that your `SurveyQuestion` type needs to use on of the keys of `TypeMap` as `propertyType`:

```
interface SurveyQuestion {
    propertyName: string,
    propertyType: keyof TypeMap,
}
```

---

When you define `question`, you don't want to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) it as `SurveyQuestion[]`. You need the compiler to keep track of the particular `propertyName` and `propertyType` values inside the initializing array literal, but if you annotate the variable property as `SurveyQuestion[]` the compiler will forget all those details.   So you want to write `const questions = ...` and not `const questions: SurveyQuestion[] = ...`.

And even that's not quite enough; the compiler won't realize you care about the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of those property values unless you tell it so.  Normally a value like `[{a: "abc", x: "xyz"}, {a: "def", x: "uvw"}]` will be inferred as type `Array<{a: string, x: string}>`, even without an annotation.  It's more common for people to want a type like that then something very specific about `"abc"` and `"xyz"`.  But you want the most specific type possible, so you can do so with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const questions = [
    { propertyName: "isNewUser", propertyType: "boolean" },
    { propertyName: "satisfactionScore", propertyType: "number" },
    { propretyName: "comments", propertyType: "string" },
] as const;
```

And IntelliSense shows you that the type of `questions` is:

```
/* const questions: readonly [{
    readonly propertyName: "isNewUser";
    readonly propertyType: "boolean";
}, {
    readonly propertyName: "satisfactionScore";
    readonly propertyType: "number";
}, {
    readonly propretyName: "comments";
    readonly propertyType: "string";
}] */
```

So that's enough information to work with now, hooray!

---

But note that we haven't used `SurveyQuestion` at all.  The compiler didn't realize that we wanted `SurveyQuestion`s and so it didn't catch that I wrote `propretyName` instead of `propertyName` in there.  Oops!

To fix that, you can use the new [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to have the compiler check that your initializer is an array of `SurveyQuestion`s without widening the variable to that type:

```
const questions = [
    { propertyName: "isNewUser", propertyType: "boolean" },
    { propertyName: "satisfactionScore", propertyType: "number" },
    { propretyName: "comments", propertyType: "string" }, // error!
//    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Did you mean to write 'propertyName'?
] as const satisfies ReadonlyArray<SurveyQuestion>;
```

Now the compiler has caught the error and we can fix it:

```
const questions = [
    { propertyName: "isNewUser", propertyType: "boolean" },
    { propertyName: "satisfactionScore", propertyType: "number" },
    { propertyName: "comments", propertyType: "string" },
    // { propertyName: "anotherProp", propertyType: "date" }
] as const satisfies ReadonlyArray<SurveyQuestion>;
```

Okay, great.

---

Now all  we have to do is define `SurveyWithQuestions` in terms of `questions`.  First we can get the type of `questions` using [the TypeScript `typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html), and index into it with `number` to get the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) if its element types:

```
type QuestionType = typeof questions[number];

/* type QuestionType = {
    readonly propertyName: "isNewUser";
    readonly propertyType: "boolean";
} | {
    readonly propertyName: "satisfactionScore";
    readonly propertyType: "number";
} | {
    readonly propertyName: "comments";
    readonly propertyType: "string";
} */
```

And now we can [iterate over that union and remap it to object properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
type ResponseFormat = {
    [T in QuestionType as T["propertyName"]]:
    TypeMap[T["propertyType"]]
}

/* type ResponseFormat = {
    isNewUser: boolean;
    satisfactionScore: number;
    comments: string;
} */
```

And finally, we can extend it with any other "static" properties to get `SurveyQuestions`:

```
interface SurveyWithQuestions extends ResponseFormat {
    date: Date;
    username: string;
}
```

---

Let's test it out:

```
let survey1: SurveyWithQuestions = {
    date: new Date("1/1/2023"),
    username: "johndoe",
    isNewUser: true,
    satisfactionScore: 5,
    comments: "happy user",
}; // okay
```

So that works as desired.  Let's see what happens if we add a line to our `questions` definition:

```
const questions = [
    { propertyName: "isNewUser", propertyType: "boolean" },
    { propertyName: "satisfactionScore", propertyType: "number" },
    { propertyName: "comments", propertyType: "string" },
    { propertyName: "dateOfBirth", propertyType: "date" } // <-- add this
] as const satisfies ReadonlyArray<SurveyQuestion>;

let survey1: SurveyWithQuestions = { // error!
    date: new Date("1/1/2023"),
    username: "johndoe",
    isNewUser: true,
    satisfactionScore: 5,
    comments: "happy user",
};
```

// Property 'dateOfBirth' is missing in type ...
// but required in type 'SurveyWithQuestions'.

So the compiler now expects a `dateOfBirth` property to exist.  Let's give it one:

```
let survey1: SurveyWithQuestions = {
    date: new Date("1/1/2023"),
    username: "johndoe",
    isNewUser: true,
    satisfactionScore: 5,
    comments: "happy user",
    dateOfBirth: "yesterday" // error! 
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
};
```

Oops, wrong type:

```
let survey1: SurveyWithQuestions = {
    date: new Date("1/1/2023"),
    username: "johndoe",
    isNewUser: true,
    satisfactionScore: 5,
    comments: "happy user",
    dateOfBirth: new Date(Date.now() - 8.64e7)
}; // okay
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=21&ssc=32&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECydPIDeAUMmcgEYD2VANhHCAFyU32MDcp5IArgLYVoLPoOhdyyAM5gooAOYsZckPInkAJnEgsAItojqyAemPI4GjeZDpkIOPwgBaMFRdYU-fJgVTk6Kl47CAgrAAtoCGIAX2JiUEhYRBQAZV4oADcIdABFXggZYCoQIm4yTCgqbCgwdAA5BwglWQUAGjLkCqroWoxsFgBrbKoYNA88THbY4gRimWQAR3zCueQAXmQAbQ7CTsrq2obHFgAiYCk6iAB3AFUpaBPWve6a9D6m5BPqOgYQE+Rou1JLsugd6o1TlJtOd4AgwEUQClZlAII9nmD3qdREIoP9ATt0T1wcdPrN+I5wFI0aCiZjPsoFHigeRTERCa8jh8TlpIAB5GAAIWANTC1P2tI8px5qIByFZAB4nE5zJZkGAwudiABdcx+WYgeZQ+FSGDAArIABKDA0xVo6AAglAoHB0PK0plsnkCvDigA+LjEYwAKmQ+vmS29CKkLBRFlttk2JEksZtIDt7MOEM+50ut3uuKMyBT8Yzb0ln2+7D+XEBpWT1pLNI5WZORphiB9iORqMLxbTtibvXLJ2xDxrTyT5D76cHxK5ZIpYCpvYb-dLdNbLVUJxrOqDxjiYZ+ADpaFR5AAKCMrA0ASjitWwyC9N-e6zVHhGi2Wnakm1HUBalwwYfk+L6dm+GyTmQ04DuKzYkmcFzXHcY4dLB67DpWvw7jEyAAD51lOq4zvBmaIW2JodgiSJUCiuH1nGa6zhuAG4dEBFETBJFwS85HzlQ5IQJSDHEUxpF8WW-T0lu8jscg+5xMQj4oFaUiYHMEAAGJ0V4YDvtBWyoMgoDPj+CJvnAfioJsJyzpyJxalqTAdO8EybDZdlkVJqJOTEgYhiploFBpBrabp2gGR0OYofmLDYZwHSUbCna0SiIgCDihYLsJS7NCoah4Yp8TgNAsKpOkWToAA6sA6rgVGyAQAAHpAIAaH4amhfcOlQHpXHINKegGIWvD5vYJIMqoNZxPQ+lSJV2QAIwsO6VW1fV5mrFBHRDcEVzIPokAXicS3GGdABMAAMF0AMwnLezJkGN0ATVyABWVBhO1VCok9JnIXmwhqlA+T-cl1HFGlHwAKz-TllKnGE3i2C9uL-ay0r8kKIoiNch0GBeR0QMeIBUFcF63sgyoABzHgAbAALBAADsVMKkqKpWOqmrRBwcpmFQAwukpQA)